# The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the argument

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, ssas-2012

I just want to get the invoices distinct count of sales on March. I got this MDX query.

My MDX Query:

```
select 
distinctcount([Measures].[Sales #]) on columns,
--[Measures].[Sales #] on columns,
non empty ([Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group]) on rows
from
(
select 
{
    [Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]
}
ON columns
from [F1_SalesBI])
```

But I got the following error, whenever I tried executing this.

```
Executing the query ...
The Axis0 function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric expression was used.
Execution complete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the definition from `msdn`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145519.aspx

Syntax:

> DistinctCount(Set_Expression)

You're doing this when you use Measures as the argument:

```
DistinctCount(Numeric_Expression)
```

Something like the following should hopefully run ok:

```
WITH 
  SET [mySet] AS 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group] * {[Measures].[Sales #]} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[setDistCount] AS 
    DistinctCount([mySet]) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[setDistCount]
   ,[Measures].[Sales #]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Customer].[Store Group].[Store Group] ON 1
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]} ON 0
  FROM [F1_SalesBI]
);
```

To return the number of invoices for the month try the following:

```
WITH 
  SET [mySet] AS 
    {[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]}  * {[Measures].[Sales #]} 
  MEMBER [Measures].[setDistCount] AS 
    DistinctCount([mySet]) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[setDistCount]
  } ON 0
FROM [F1_SalesBI];
```

If the above returns 1 then try inspecting the set via this script:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  {[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]}  * {[Measures].[Sales #]}  ON 0
FROM [F1_SalesBI];
```

Does this just return 1 member?

How about this (without the set braces around the measure)?:

```
SELECT 
  {} on 0,
  {[Calendar].[Month].[March 2015]}  * [Measures].[Sales #]  ON 0
FROM [F1_SalesBI];
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks. This returns sum of the [Sales #]. Sales # means invoice number, I don't want to sum the invoice numbers which isn't needed. I need to count how many invoices are there! Please help!

Comment: Hi - I've not used the `sum` function. Can you tell me another Measure in your cube please?

Comment: Quantity, Net Sales, GP, GP%, COGS, COGS%, Sales # are the measures in my cube. I need to know how many invoices (count) we generated in the particular month?

Comment: This simply returns 1. :-(

Comment: did you inspect the set?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to inspect the set?

Comment: 'without the set braces around the measure' does return no values. :-(

Comment: do you have an invoice hierarchy with members that can be counted? Problem is that `[Measures].[Sales #]` is a single member of the Measures hierarchy so that is why we got a return of 1.